# Testing value of field using an element that endsWith

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a SharePoint edit form, where I want to make one of the Y/N fields read-only. This field toggles visibility of two other fields.
I have converted read-only to a bound label field. If the value this field that ends with "_ff5_1" is Yes, then I want the two toggled fields to be hidden, if not, then show them.

Here's the code from my first try at it

```
if ($("span[id$=_ff5_1]").val() == "Yes") {    
    $("tr.anon").hide(); 
} else {
    $("tr.anon").show();
}
```

I thought I might be trying to do too much at one time with the above code, so I revised it to the following

```
$("span[id$='_ff5_1']") //select element
   if $(this).val() ==='Yes' { //test val
      $("tr.anon").hide(); // hide name & email rows
} else {
      $("tr.anon").show();
}
```

However, neither seems to be hiding rows if based on the value of Y/N field.

UPDATE1
@Nicola: I tried your suggestion but it did not work. I believe the issue is that the field ($("span[id$='_ff5_1']")) is no longer an input field- I had converted it to a label field in order to make it read-only.

```
$("span[id$='_ff5_1']").each(function() { //returns a collection of elements that must be iterated through using each
        if (this.value == "Yes") { //test value 
            $("tr.anon").hide(); 
        } else {
            $("tr.anon").show();
        }   
     });
```

Also, I believe the fields I am trying to hide are not parents of the label field, but are children of the label field.

Thanks for your feedback.

UPDATE2:
Here's the src code of the bound label and the two text fields I wish to toggle the visibility based on.

```
<tr>
    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel"><H3 class="ms-standardheader">Anonymous</H3></td>
    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
       <span id="ctl00_m_g_e959bdad_1c52_41a7_b23f_564bc84c2497_ff5_1">Yes</span>
       <br>Would you like to remain anonymous?</td>
</tr>
<tr class="anon">
    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel"><H3 class="ms-standardheader">Name</H3></td>
    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
       <span dir="none"><input name="ctl00$m$g_e959bdad_1c52_41a7_b23f_564bc84c2497$ff6_1$ctl00$ctl00$TextField" type="text" maxlength="255" id="ctl00_m_g_e959bdad_1c52_41a7_b23f_564bc84c2497_ff6_1_ctl00_ctl00_TextField" title="name" class="ms-long" /><br></span></td>
</tr>
<tr class="anon">
    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel"><H3 class="ms-standardheader">Email</H3></td>
    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
       <span dir="none"><input name="ctl00$m$g_e959bdad_1c52_41a7_b23f_564bc84c2497$ff7_1$ctl00$ctl00$TextField" type="text" maxlength="255" id="ctl00_m_g_e959bdad_1c52_41a7_b23f_564bc84c2497_ff7_1_ctl00_ctl00_TextField" title="email" class="ms-long" /><br></span></td>
</tr>
```

UPDATE3: Val() should only be used to get the value of input elements. B/c I have converted my input element to a label, I should use .text(). http://api.jquery.com/text/

FINAL UPDATE:

```
$("span[id$='_ff5_1']").each(function() { //returns a collection of elements that must be iterated through using each
  if ($(this).text() == "Yes") { //test value returned from non-input field 
      $("tr.anon").hide(); 
  } else {
      $("tr.anon").show();
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should do something like

```
$("span[id$=_ff5_1]").each(function(){
  if (this.value == "Yes") {    
    $(this).closest("tr").find('.anon').hide(); 
  } else {
    $(this).closest("tr").find('.anon').show();
  }
});
```

You must do something like this because `$("span[id$=_ff5_1]")` return a collection of elemens and you must iterate on them. 
Then i just got the closest `<tr>` element that is a parent of the current input element and hide/show the elements with class `anon` , nut maybe you need something different

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Seeing it reminds me that I am missing parens and some closing tags.